# What is the point of Jekyll in a single page website?

Tags: jekyll

My boss gave me a single page website to develop, and Jekyll is mandatory. of course I dont directly question my hierarchy. I'm not really used to jekyll so perhaps there is something I didn't get. How would you justify its use for a single page website ? (and not a single page app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jekyll does not necessarily operate on the webpage level. With [Data Files](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/), you can have data in multiple files that can be rendered on the same webpage.

Besides that, general advantages might be the [template engine](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/) with filters, support for [Sass and CoffeeScript](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/), various [plugins](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/), etc.

If it’s useful in this specific case would depend on the site, your workflow, and especially what you’d use instead of Jekyll.